# ACTIVE RECORD ERROR: Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=1 [WHERE (`customers`.`company_id` IS NOT NULL) AND `customers`.`company_id` = ?] RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, factory-bot

Im running RSPEC tests on my Ruby on Rails Controller, here is the controller action I am testing:

**CONTROLLER CODE:**

```
class Customers::AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer

  def index
    @accounts = @customer.accounts
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  def set_customer
    @customer = current_member.company.customers.find(params[:customer_id])
  end
end
```

**Here is my RSPEC Test Code:**

```
before do
  @member   = FactoryGirl.create(:member)
  @company  = FactoryGirl.create(:company, owner_id: @member.id) 
  @customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer_john_human,company_id:@company.id)
end

describe "GET INDEX" do 
  it "gets the index html page" do 
    get :index, {:customer_id=>@customer.id, :format=>:json}
  end
end
```

**THE ERROR:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=1 [WHERE (`customers`.`company_id` IS NOT NULL)   AND `customers`.`company_id` = ?]
    # ./app/controllers/customers/accounts_controller.rb:87:in `set_customer'
    # ./spec/support/engine_controller.rb:25:in `process_action'
    # ./spec/support/engine_controller.rb:3:in `get'
    # ./spec/controllers/customers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am unsure what `customer.company_id = ?` means, - if i do :

```
puts @customer.inspect
```

I get the following output:

```
#<Customer id: 2, user_id: nil, title: nil, first_name: "John", last_name: "Kusu", created_at: "2015-04-27 18:42:00", updated_at: "2015-04-27 18:42:00", deleted_at: nil, company_name: nil, company_id: 6>
```

As far as i can tell, `company_id` is defined and set as 6. I am not sure why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the current_member?

Comment: The error in the stacktrace often doesn't actually display the real company-id used in the test... but there probably was one. the ? part means you somewhere has something like `where(company_id: 42)` and Rails turns that into: `where("company_id = ?", 42)` make sense?

Comment: Now.. in your controller you have this: `current_member` -> what is that? and how would your controller get a hold of this current member? and what setup have you done in your rspec to make sure that the current-member is actually logged in. ?

Comment: Please post the code from models where you set up the associations between `Member` and `Company`, between `Company` and `Customer`. Are there multiple foreign keys in `Company` which reference `Member`, e.g. `owner_id` and `member_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a one to many relationship that is not set up correctly.

```
  def set_customer
    @customer = current_member.company.customers.find(params[:customer_id])
  end
```

This code states that current_member belongs to a company that has many customers. Of the customers that belong to that company, return the one with this id.

To implement this, your customers table needs to have a foreign key called company_id. Take a look at your db migrations and [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

Also add belongs_to to your Customer class (do this first! and test. It may be all you need.)

```
class Customers::AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer
  belongs_to :company
```